# how to duplicate shapes, in a circle?

Tags: modifiers, curve-modifier, duplicate

how to duplicate shapes, in a circle?
I would like my pillars to be all around the circle, without doing one by one... thank you!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the circle, under Object properties, Instancing, enable Vertices or Faces, and then select a single pillar, then shift_select the circle, and parent to object. If you have too many faces or vertices on the circle, add a more simple "Add :: Mesh :: Circle" and parent to that instead, after aligning the circle (radius and position) to that of the circular object:

[image]

You can control the number of vertices around the circle during the Add process (default is 32).

[image]

Also, you'll see that if you uncheck "Show Instancer", "Render" the child object (your pillar model) won't show on the final render.   You might also move your model (circle and circular wall) away from location 0/0/0, if you are "bothered" by child pillar in the viewport (I think there's a bug; unchecking Viewport *should* make the child disappear in viewport)

[image]

Comment: How do I remove the middle object when finished? or deactivate it but without deactivating what surrounds it?

Comment: @Fopsi -- on the circle object, uncheck the "Show Instancer" for Viewport and/or Render.  blender is like a hide-and-seek game!

Comment: but the problem is that it displays the circle but not the object in the middle, or the reverse the object in the middle remains and it removes everything that is around? I tried with your model too

Comment: because for me it's not for rendering but it would be to export it in OBJ

Comment: @Fopsi - I'm sorry but I don't understand. You wanted the "pillars" to be distributed around a circle, and then I though you didn't want to see the original pillar in the middle.  If you then want to "realize" the instances, then the obj will indeed import as several "pillars" in a circle.  Sometimes, there nothing like a real-time voice conversation that is not possible here.

Comment: yes it's not obvious especially since I don't speak English fluently

Comment: in fact, I'm trying to make ramparts around a house, but the problem is that with your technique, I can't remove the rampart that's in the middle

Comment: I have published an image below to show you what I would like to do but in a precise way?

Comment: @Fopsi -- there may be a bug where unchecking Viewport isn't making the child pillar disappear, but it definitely doesn't Render.  I edited my answer above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145996/discussion-between-fopsi-and-james-t).